# Why is this Compass @import not working in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, compass-sass

**test_app/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss**

```
@import 'compass';
@import 'variables';
@media only screen and (min-width: $breakpoint-medium-additional-width) {
  @import 'partials/medium-additional';
}
```

**test_app/app/assets/stylesheets/_variables.scss**

```
$breakpoint-medium-additional-width: 28em;
```

When I try to visit a page (in development), this Rails error occurs:

```
Sass::SyntaxError at /
Invalid CSS after "...nd (min-width: ": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was "$breakpoint-med..." (in /Users/ben/rails_projects/test_app/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss)
```

Why is `$breakpoint-medium-additional-width` not being set correctly?

I'm using

- Rails 3.2.11
- ruby 1.9.3
- compass 0.12.2
- compass-rails 1.0.3

Comment: You have a typo in `additional`, but that isn't the problem. Also, the import is working, otherwise you'd get an error about the file not being able to be imported.

Comment: @sevenseacat Fixed the typo, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a typo in your code. I created a new rails project, and it works fine for me.

app/assets/stylesheets/_variables.scss

```
$breakpoint-medium-additonal-width: 28em;
```

app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss

```
@import 'compass';
@import 'variables';
@media only screen and (min-width: $breakpoint-medium-additonal-width) {
  font-size: 120%;
}
```

The output application.css

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 28em) {
  font-size: 120%;
}
```

Comment: If you'll post the test_app on github, I can diagnose

Comment: Thanks, I've realised now that the @import was working. There's still something going wrong though, but I'll create a new question to prevent this one from getting confusing.